# No notification sound when using one USB port (Windows 7 64 bit)

Tags: windows-7, usb, 64-bit

I have an HP laptop (G4 250) with Windows 7 64 bit. The laptop has two USB 2.0 ports and one USB 3.0 port. The ports all work fine except one which when anything is plugged on it, no 'Device attached' notification sound is produced. The other two ports (one USB 2.0 and another USB 3.0) work well with no problems at all.

If I plug an external HDD/flash drive on the problematic port, it works just fine only that Windows does not show any notification for the new drive plugged in. No sound or even Autoplay. The drive is however visible in Explorer. If I plug in a wireless mouse transceiver, it works fine but the device does not show in 'Devices and Printers'. It does, however, show up in device manager.

I have updated all drivers and Windows too but nothing seems to correct that. I have tried removing the Intel USB 3.0 drivers and putting them back after restart, I have updated my BIOS, restarted Windows several times and the problem still persists.

I haven't installed many applications on this computer. I only have Firefox, Opera, Media Player Classic, Open Office and Flux.

What could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an issue with the USB port as another similar 2.0 version USB port is working fine with out any issue. It doesn't seems to be an issue with the driver. Check whether the port strips are in good condition or try replacing it

Comment: The port looks fine, at least to me. I just tried tranferring about 5GB on the port and it went fine. I've also installed a USB modem using the same port. Windows still does not notify no matter what device is plugged in. It just accepts the device silently.